# What is the right answer to $P^{-1}AP$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the matrices

> $$A=\pmatrix{b+8c & 2c-2b & 4b-4c \\ 4c-4a & c+8b & 2a-2c \\ 2b-2a & 4a-4b & a+8b  \\ }, P=\pmatrix{0 & 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 0 & 1 \\1 & 2 & 0  \\ } $$
>   find $P^{-1}$ and **compute $P^{-1}AP$.** Hence determine $detA$.
>   $$$$ May you  help me with the boldfaced part: The book's answer is:
>   $$P^{-1}AP=\pmatrix{9a & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 9b & 0 \\0 & 0 & 9c  \\ } $$
>   while mine is:
>   $$P^{-1}AP=\frac{1}{9}\pmatrix{64b+17a & 0 & 32b-32a \\ 32a-32b & 81b & 16a-16b \\16b-16a+36c & 72c & 81c-8a+8b  \\ } $$
>   Thanks in advance.

Comment: **HINT** Compute $AP$ first and see what it looks like. What $P^{-1}$ did you use ?

Comment: $$P^{-1}=\frac{1}{9}\pmatrix{-2 & 4 & 1 \\ 1 & -2 & 4\\4 & 1 & -2  \\ } $$

Comment: Ok, well your $P^{-1}$ is good. Now what did you get for $AP$ ?

Comment: What I was trying to show you was basically what @Andreas Caranti said. Indeed if you compute $AP$ you get: $$AP=\pmatrix{0 & 9b & 18c \\ 16b+2a & 0 & 9c+8b-8a \\ 9a & 18b & 0}$$ Now you can realize there's a pattern here (except for the second row elements) and since you don't get the correct result, there must be a problem in you original matrix. For the pattern to hold you must replace $b$ by $a$ in the second row. This is how you could've found that $(c+8b)$ had to be replaced by $(c+8a)$ ;)

Comment: Thank you again for the provided explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Your calculations *with the given $A$* are correct, but...

there's misprint in your $A$, the element in location $(2, 2)$ is $c + 8 a$. Once you change that, the book's answer will turn out to be correct.